# Unidentifiable worms appear on apartment floor

Tags: safety, cleaning, cleanout

I found some worms on my apartment floor. I can’t find anything rotten around the apartment, but I don’t know how they got there. Are those maggots?

[video link](https://streamable.com/bdivsn)

Comment: You should provide a close-up picture instead of a shaky video. Maggots don't generally flee from their food source. Are they falling from the ceiling? Is something rotting in your ceiling? Those could be Indianmeal moth larvae.

Comment: I would agree that the video is bouncing , a coin on the floor may also help as moth larva are larger than fly’s

Comment: I’ve squished them all and cleaned them up… I’ll post more images if I find them reappearing. Thank you for your input!